# Reducibility of a fourth degree polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am given the following:
Let $f(x)=x^4-a^2D$ such that $a$ and $D$ are nonzero, $a \in \mathbb{Q}, D \in \mathbb{Z}$.

In addition, I am given that $D$ is also square-free and $D \neq 1$

i) if $D \neq -1$ then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

ii) if $D=-1$ then it is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if either $2a \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ or $-2a \in \mathbb{Q}^2$

I am not really sure how to do these. I have been using Eisenstein and the rational root test, but this is a more generic polynomial. Can someone demonstrate how to show these two things?

Comment: Can you do the "if" part of item ii? That seems like it's the simplest of the bunch. You can show your work by clicking "edit" just below your question. I suspect that the following factorization might be useful: $x^4 + 1 = (x^2 + \sqrt{2} x + 1) (x^2 - \sqrt{2}x + 1)$. But I haven't actually checked that.

Comment: Yes! Your factorization makes (ii) fairly straightforward. I am still unsure of (i)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general fact: if $F$ is a field whose characteristic is not $2$ and $\lambda\in F$, then $x^4-\lambda$ is reducible if and only if either $\lambda=r^2$ for some $r\in F$ or $-4\lambda=r^4$ for some $r\in F$.  When $F$ has characteristic $2$, $x^4-\lambda$ is reducible if and only if $\lambda=r^2$ for some $r\in F$.

When you apply this result to the OP's example via $\lambda=a^2D$, the hypotheses imply $\lambda$ cannot be a square and $-4\lambda$ cannot be a fourth power if $D\ne -1$.  If $D=-1$, then $-4\lambda=4a^2$, which is a fourth power precisely when $\pm 2a$ is a square.

To prove the initial assertion, note first that if $\lambda=r^2$, then $x^4-\lambda=(x^2-r)(x^2+r)$.  If $-4\lambda=r^4$ and $F$ does not have characteristic $2$, then $x^4-\lambda=(x^2+rx+\frac12r^2)(x^2-rx+\frac12r^2)$.

For the converse, if $\lambda$ is not a square, then $x^4-\lambda$ has no roots, so any factorization of it must be equivalent to  $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2-ax+d)$.  Expanding this and equating it to $x^4-\lambda$ leads to the equation $a(d-b)=0$ (consider the coefficient of $x$), so either $a=0$ or $b=d$.  When $a=0$, we have to have $d=-b$ and $b^2=\lambda$.  When $a\ne 0$, we have $b=d$ and $a^2=2b$ (look at the coefficient of $x^2$).  This immediately implies $F$ cannot have characteristic $2$.  Since $bd=-\lambda$, we get $-4\lambda=a^4$.